# How can i plot multiple distribution plots with Seaborn?

Tags: python, plot, seaborn, distribution

I am not experienced with plotting in Python. But I have managed to plot a signle distribution plot with Seaborn.

example code:

```
sns.displot(SD_frame_A,kind="kde")
```

example plot: [image]

So I tryed to plot three of them in one graph:

example code:

```
sns.displot(SD_frame_A,kind="kde")
sns.displot(SD_frame_S,kind="kde")
sns.displot(SD_frame_D,kind="kde")
plt.show()
```

But this will only plot the three distribution separately. Does anyone how I can plot both 3 distribution in one plot?

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that with `displot` because that is a figure-level function. But you can use  `kdeplot` and provide an axes object:

```
ax = plt.axes()
sns.kdeplot(SD_frame_A, ax=ax)
sns.kdeplot(SD_frame_S, ax=ax)
sns.kdeplot(SD_frame_D, ax=ax)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you, but it returns the following error: ValueError: cannot reindex on an axis with duplicate labels

Comment: Are the frames pandas Series? Try transforming them to numpy arrays with `SD_frame_A.values`.

Comment: Yes they are in pandas series so I changed it to a dataframe which did not work either. I will try your option now

Comment: Sure, happy it worked!

Comment: Well it only worked for a "kdeplot", when I use the "displot" it still plots them separately. And it even becomes slower

Comment: And gives three time this message in the kernel: \lib\site-packages\seaborn\distributions.py:2211: UserWarning: `displot` is a figure-level function and does not accept the ax= paramter. You may wish to try kdeplot.
  warnings.warn(msg, UserWarning). So that makes sense :)

Comment: yes, `displot` is the wrong function for that.

Comment: But isn't the 'kdeplot' used for non normally distributed data?

Comment: I think `kdeplot` uses a Gaussian kernel, but I'm pretty sure that `displot(kind='kde')` uses `kdeplot` inside. If you want to fit a gaussian distribution (not a mixture of those), you'll have to do something different altogether